# Cookies not working in some browsers 

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-4.0

I've encountered a strange problem...

1 of my website users can't get all cookies to be written, therefore some features on my website doesn't work.

And I can't seem to figure out why this is, in Google Chrome the authentication cookie is written just fine, but another cookie required for the website is not written (a sort of data dump).

In Internet explorer it doesn't write any cookies at all..

I have set both browsers to have the exact same settings as that of a working browser, but it seems to make no difference whatsoever.

Now I'm wondering whether it's my website that's the problem, or if it's the users computer. cause this is 1 user that has a problem, while i have arround 300 other users that don't have this problem at all..

I hope you can shed some light on this, because it's quite frustrating..

Comment: Can you post an example of the HTTP response headers from when the cookies are supposed to be set?

Answer (score 2):

The most likely cause is that you don't have a compact privacy policy set in the response where you are setting the cookies.

Without a compact privacy policy, some browsers (most notably IE) will reject the cookies, particularly if they are third-party (not from the same domain as the URL in the address bar), or if the browser has its security mode set to High.

For ASP.NET, here's some code from my book that will set a basic policy:

```
this.Response.AddHeader("P3P", "CP=\"NID DSP CAO COR\"");
```

You will need to do that whenever you set a cookie.

Another possible cause is that there are too many cookies or their total size is too large, but since it's working in some browsers and not others, the P3P issue seems more likely.